# PDO Binding Multiple Insert Statements to Mapped Array Values

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am attempting to create an order/invoice system.

I have one table for `orders`, and one table for the line items: `orders_items`.

I am trying to insert all the line items in one go using the `PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES` attribute.

I understand about the the security risk, there is no user input that goes into this db. This is all behind the scenes.

When I parse through the `$order_item` array, I am creating multiple INSERT sql statements with the placeholders.

However when I go to bind the params, it appears in the DB that only the last item in the `$order_item` array is added.

Here is how the `$data` variable looks for the `$order_item` array.

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]    =>  string(8) "A red item"
    ["quantity"]=>  int(1)
    ["price"]   =>  string(1) "1"
    ["order_id"]=>  string(2) "44"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["name"]    =>  string(9) "A blue item"
    ["quantity"]=>  int(1)
    ["price"]   =>  string(1) "2"
    ["order_id"]=>  string(2) "44"
  }
}
```

The Build Insert statements will create this:

```
INSERT INTO orders_items ( name, quantity, price, order_id ) VALUES ( :name, :quantity, :price, :order_id );
INSERT INTO orders_items ( name, quantity, price, order_id ) VALUES ( :name, :quantity, :price, :order_id );
```

And during the place-holder-value binding phase what I am trying to do is this:

```
:name = "A red item", :quantity = 1, :price = 1, :order_id = 44
:name = "A blue item", :quantity = 1, :price = 2, :order_id = 44
```

But only this one gets inserted into the DB:

```
:name = "A blue item", :quantity = 1, :price = 2, :order_id = 44
```

Here is my Create function

```
public static function create ($data = []) {

$order_info = $data['order_info'];
$orderID = //do first insert and get the record ID

$order_item = $data['order_item'];

//Attach the order number to the each item in the $order_item array
//This way during the SQL for each, the order_id, which is a required column, will be added
foreach ($order_item as $key=>$value){
       $order_item[$key]["order_id"] = $orderID;
}

//Build the INSERT statements
$sql = "";
foreach ($order_item as $item){
  $sql .= "INSERT INTO  orders_items ";
  $sql .= " ( " . implode(", ", array_keys($item)) . " )";
  $sql .= " VALUES ( :" . implode(", :", array_keys($item)) . " ); ";
}


$db = static::getDB();
$db->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, 1 );
$stmt = $db->prepare( $sql );

//BIND ALL THE ORDER ITEM PLACEHOLDERS TO THEIR VALUES.
foreach ($order_item as $item) {
    foreach ($item as $linekey => $linevalue) {
        $stmt->bindValue(":" . $linekey, $linevalue, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    }
}

   return $stmt->execute();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this possible? Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do it this way, it's much simpler:

```
$cols = implode(',', array_keys($order_item[0]));

function colon_prefix($param) { return ":$param"; }

$params = implode(',', array_map("colon_prefix", array_keys($order_item[0])));

$sql = "INSERT INTO orders_items ($cols) VALUES ($params)";

$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

foreach ($order_item as $item) {
    $stmt->execute($item);
}
```

You can re-execute a prepared statement multiple times, passing a different array to each execution. This is just as good as the multi-query code, and much easier to code and easier to read.

I never use multi-query (multiple statements in one SQL query string). It's complicated to get right, and there's no benefit to doing it.

When you bind values for params, at one time you had to put a colon prefix on the key, to match the parameter placeholder. But they fixed that so long ago that even the PHP version they fixed it in is now deprecated. You can use plain strings as the bind keys.

You don't need to use `bindValue()` at all, just pass an array to `execute()`.

Also, the code above assumes your column names don't need to be delimited. That is, they are not SQL reserved words, and they don't contain special characters like whitespace, punctuation, or international characters.

Comment: You just blew my mind. Thank you! That was perfect. Are you saying I do not need to 'bindValue()' only because no user data is involved?

Comment: Passing an array to `execute()` does exactly the same thing as `bindValue()`. It protects against SQL injection risks, but it's more concise code. I have no idea why so few people use this method.

Comment: Do you have a blog or some tutorials that I can follow/learn from?

Comment: I recommend https://phpdelusions.net/pdo and https://www.phptherightway.com

Comment: I don't code in PHP much anymore. My subjective opinion about scripting language preference is: Ruby > Python > Bash > Javascript > PHP > Lua

Answer (score -1):

print in the for loop after getting the index element sum.

```
$arr_count = count($array);
for($i = 0; $i <= $arr_count; $i++){
    $insert_ord_query = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO orders(name, quantity, price, order_id) VALUES(:name, :quantity, :price, :order_id)");
    $inser_ord_query->execute(array(
        ":name" => $array[$i]['name'],
        ":quantity" => $array[$i]['quantity'],
        ":price" => $array[$i]['price'],
        ":order_id" => $array[$i]['order_id']
    ));
}
echo "success";
```

Comment: Sorry but this would always lock you into column names. It doesn't provide an abstract way of doing multiple inserts.

Comment: do not the columns in the array need to be added?